# Is there any way to show vidoe file on web page for free?

Tags: html, video, video-streaming

Im looking for a plugin or any open source for showing video file on webpage. but there are sooooooo many things and I can't find different things between those.

I aleady know that HTML5 and web browser provide a way. Then why there are such many sites and companies ?

And can you give me any recommendation on open source or site or company or anything?

Comment: you need to spend a time to compare and pick the best suitable framework for your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches to show video on a web page:

1. Host video to some video streaming website like youtube etc..
2. Host it on your server.

Best way is to upload video to youtube and embed the same to your web page like:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
</iframe>
```

Alternatively if you want to host video on your server then there are multiple frameworks to do this:

`media element js` http://mediaelementjs.com/

`videojs` http://videojs.com/

Comment: thank you so much. I was lose the way. I did not know like "where do I start?". As your answer, I will visit `media element js` and `videojs`.